# Understanding Dependency Injection, Simple Example

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Below is a very basic console App example that I put on understanding Dependency Injection & IOC. I somehow could not see the value as in this case I still need to modify my program.cs to inject the new implementation of Interface. Also, how unit testing fits into this?

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace UnderstandingDI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serPro = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton<IMessage, Messaging>()
                .BuildServiceProvider();
            var bar = serPro.GetService<IMessage>();
            bar.PrintMessage("Hello World!----");
        }
    }
}
```

IMessage.cs

```
namespace UnderstandingDI
{
    public interface IMessage
    {
        public void PrintMessage(string Msg);
    }
}
```

Messaging.cs

```
using System;

namespace UnderstandingDI
{
    public class Messaging : IMessage
    {
        public void PrintMessage(string Msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Msg + "From Messaging");
        }
    }
}
```

NewMessaging.cs

```
using System;

namespace UnderstandingDI
{
    class NewMessaging : IMessage
    {
        public void PrintMessage(string Msg)
        {
            if (Msg.StartsWith("Hello"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Msg starting with Hello");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, if I have to swap `Messaging.cs` implementation with `NewMessaging.cs` which both implement `IMessage` interface, I still need to modify my `Program.cs` to inject this `NewMessaging.cs` like this:

```
var serPro = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton<IMessage, NewMessaging>()
                .BuildServiceProvider();
```

If so, why MS claims that DI addresses one prob of `To replace MyDependency with a different implementation, the class must be modified`
src:`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1`

What am I missing?

Comment: but you have nothing but `IMessage` implementations to test here ... also `NewMessaging` is not well testable as it just put something into STD OUT ... obviously it would be better to inject some `IWriter` into `NewMessaging`  and in tests you would use different implementation of `IWriter` (fx mock to test value writen by `PrintMessage`) and different on default(fx IWrite that writes output to STD OUT)

Comment: If you step back and look at the IMessage in context of another component, let's say "ChatWindow" - that component can now be built on the abstraction IMessage rather than Messaging or NewMessaging. The implementation can change or be swapped out entirely and the ChatWindow won't need any code changes. When you want to write unit tests for the ChatWindow, you can use a mock of IMessage to do this.

Comment: Maybe add more dependent services to `Messaging` will help a better understanding. Say if you have `IMessagePrinter` injected into messaging, you could have different implementations that print message to console or to file. And you only need to change registration code not your messaging class when you change implementation used.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there is no dependency injection.

Dependency injection literally means: you *inject* a dependency into a class, you don't construct it yourself and don't actively ask some other component for that dependency.

There is no class in your example that actually has a dependency (except of the `Program` of course).

The `Main` method in your `Program.cs` is a *composition root*. This is where you wire-up the DI container ("service provider"). Of course, you will need to modify it when you want to change the implementations.

Now, imagine you have a class that *does* have a dependency `IMessage`:

```
class ChatBot
{
    private readonly IMessage message;

    public ChatBot(IMessage message) => _message = message;

    public void Greet() => _message.PrintMessage("Hello World!");
}
```

If you replace the `IMessage` implementation in the composition root, the `ChatBot` class won't even know it. You don't have to touch that class.

Imagine you have 50 classes that all use `IMessage` to print messages. Changing the implementation still causes the change in the composition root, *but only there*. The other 50 classes don't need to be changed.

This also helps you in unit testing. If you want to test the `ChatBot` class, you can mock the `IMessage` dependency in a way you need it. You also have a direct knowledge, that the `ChatBot` class *needs* an `IMessage` and nothing besides that. Your code is testable then (no hidden calls to unknown singletons, static classes etc.)

Hope my explanation helps. Consider reading a great book "Dependency Injection in .NET" where you'll find a lot of good ideas about designing maintainable software in .NET.

Comment: so what if ChatBot Class depends on more than one Interface like `IMessage` and `IEmail` do we need to mock both interfaces to test ChatBot class? Also, if it has additional methods than `IMessage` how does this be handled? please comment